# Plow Truck was working great but after 20 minutes it began to smoke, stalled and now will crank but will not start

Tags: chevrolet, truck, smoke, cranks-wont-run, blazer

My plow truck is a 4.3 1991 Blazer, it was working great but after 20 minutes or so it began to smoke, then stalled out and now it will crank but will not start.  The oil, transmission (auto) fluid, and gas are all ok.  I hope someone can help me out

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have not given very much detail to go on. Use the [edit] feature to add things like; if the Check Engine light on. Do you know what the source of the smoke was? Was it under the hood, under the vehicle, from the exhaust, etc? Is there spark? Fuel getting to the engine?

Comment: Does it have any coolant?

Comment: it does have coolant, there is no check engine light on,  I believe the smoke came from under the hood but alot of it came into the cabin (inside the truck) it seemed to have a burnt plastic smell to it.  So now its cranking but not starting

Comment: This question seems eerily similar - are you Thomas ?? https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/52796/10976

Comment: yes I am the first post wasn't receiving any replies so I figured I would make a new one

Comment: Please don't create a new account and ask the same question again. This only muddles the works.